# ST_Intersects gives GEOSIntersects TopologyException side location conflict on two valid geometries

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have two geometries, one is a GeometryCollection, the other is a Polygon, when using ST_IsValid both are true and ST_IsValidReason both put out Valid Geometry. When using both in a ST_Intersects it gives a TopologyException.

I am using PostGIS 3.2.2 and GEOS version 3.11 (alpine)

queries are:

```sql
SELECT ST_IsValid('SRID=28992;GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POLYGON((78499.527 457927.715,78501.803 457927.007,78503.244 457927.292,78503.25 457927.293,78507.658 457928.166,78508.442 457928.322,78508.52 457928.325,78508.596 457928.304,78508.661 457928.261,78508.709 457928.199,78508.736 457928.126,78509.095 457926.316,78509.097 457926.238,78509.075 457926.163,78509.031 457926.099,78508.97 457926.051,78508.896 457926.025,78508.818 457926.022,78508.743 457926.043,78508.679 457926.087,78508.631 457926.148,78508.604 457926.221,78508.294 457927.783,78507.756 457927.676,78503.342 457926.802,78503.336 457926.801,78501.835 457926.503,78501.774 457926.499,78501.715 457926.51,78499.379 457927.237,78499.097 457927.325,78495.631 457928.405,78491.179 457929.791,78491.124 457929.816,78491.077 457929.853,78488.757 457932.162,78487.042 457933.868,78484.937 457935.961,78477.138 457943.719,78476.817 457944.038,78476.768 457944.106,78476.556 457944.545,78476.516 457944.613,78476.513 457944.619,78476.476 457944.689,78476.438 457944.758,78476.434 457944.766,78476.403 457944.83,78476.373 457944.892,78476.368 457944.903,78476.344 457944.959,78476.319 457945.015,78476.314 457945.029,78476.296 457945.078,78476.278 457945.128,78476.271 457945.148,78476.26 457945.191,78476.249 457945.234,78476.244 457945.254,78476.243 457945.264,78476.238 457945.3,78476.233 457945.336,78476.231 457945.369,78476.231 457945.383,78476.233 457945.412,78476.234 457945.442,78476.238 457945.47,78476.249 457945.513,78476.257 457945.535,78476.263 457945.551,78476.27 457945.569,78476.278 457945.584,78476.285 457945.6,78476.292 457945.616,78476.301 457945.632,78476.31 457945.648,78476.314 457945.655,78476.318 457945.662,78476.328 457945.679,78476.338 457945.695,78476.346 457945.707,78476.358 457945.724,78476.37 457945.741,78476.378 457945.751,78476.391 457945.768,78476.404 457945.785,78476.411 457945.794,78476.427 457945.812,78476.442 457945.83,78476.449 457945.838,78476.465 457945.856,78476.482 457945.874,78476.488 457945.88,78476.506 457945.898,78477.863 457947.273,78478.147 457947.561,78480.574 457950.018,78481.491 457956.548,78481.786 457958.651,78481.82 457958.893,78482.33 457962.522,78482.662 457964.882,78482.666 457964.913,78482.67 457964.944,78482.675 457964.975,78482.679 457965.006,78482.683 457965.037,78482.688 457965.068,78482.692 457965.099,78482.696 457965.13,78482.701 457965.161,78482.705 457965.192,78482.71 457965.222,78482.714 457965.254,78482.718 457965.284,78482.723 457965.315,78482.727 457965.346,78482.732 457965.377,78482.736 457965.407,78482.74 457965.438,78482.744 457965.469,78482.748 457965.5,78482.753 457965.531,78482.757 457965.562,78482.761 457965.594,78482.764 457965.609,78482.787 457965.684,78482.831 457965.748,78482.894 457965.795,78482.968 457965.821,78483.046 457965.822,78483.121 457965.799,78483.185 457965.754,78483.232 457965.691,78483.257 457965.617,78483.259 457965.539,78483.256 457965.524,78483.252 457965.494,78483.248 457965.463,78483.244 457965.432,78483.239 457965.401,78483.235 457965.37,78483.231 457965.339,78483.227 457965.307,78483.222 457965.276,78483.218 457965.245,78483.213 457965.214,78483.209 457965.183,78483.205 457965.153,78483.2 457965.122,78483.196 457965.09,78483.192 457965.06,78483.187 457965.029,78483.183 457964.998,78483.178 457964.967,78483.174 457964.936,78483.17 457964.905,78483.165 457964.874,78483.161 457964.843,78483.157 457964.812,78482.826 457962.452,78482.316 457958.823,78482.282 457958.581,78481.987 457956.478,78481.058 457949.866,78481.034 457949.79,78480.988 457949.725,78478.503 457947.209,78478.219 457946.921,78476.862 457945.548,78476.847 457945.532,78476.833 457945.517,78476.82 457945.502,78476.808 457945.488,78476.796 457945.475,78476.786 457945.462,78476.776 457945.448,78476.768 457945.437,78476.76 457945.427,78476.753 457945.415,78476.746 457945.404,78476.742 457945.395,78476.737 457945.386,78476.732 457945.377,78476.733 457945.367,78476.736 457945.347,78476.743 457945.32,78476.752 457945.287,78476.766 457945.249,78476.781 457945.206,78476.802 457945.158,78476.824 457945.108,78476.852 457945.049,78476.881 457944.991,78476.916 457944.925,78476.953 457944.856,78476.994 457944.785,78477.002 457944.77,78477.2 457944.362,78477.49 457944.073,78485.289 457936.315,78487.394 457934.222,78489.109 457932.516,78491.386 457930.25,78495.779 457928.883,78499.246 457927.803,78499.527 457927.715)),POLYGON((78462.657 457906.654,78462.579 457906.653,78462.505 457906.675,78462.441 457906.72,78462.394 457906.782,78462.368 457906.856,78462.366 457906.934,78462.412 457907.271,78461.151 457908.462,78461.103 457908.524,78461.077 457908.598,78461.074 457908.676,78461.096 457908.751,78461.141 457908.816,78461.203 457908.864,78461.276 457908.89,78461.354 457908.892,78461.429 457908.87,78461.494 457908.826,78462.848 457907.546,78462.896 457907.484,78462.922 457907.41,78462.924 457907.331,78462.862 457906.867,78462.839 457906.791,78462.794 457906.727,78462.732 457906.68,78462.657 457906.654)),POLYGON((79373.448 458075.366,79373.244 458075.421,79373.155 458075.612,79373.155 458079.509,79373.28 458079.726,79373.53 458079.726,79373.655 458079.509,79373.655 458075.612,79373.597 458075.452,79373.448 458075.366)),POLYGON((78475.323 457975.019,78481.202 457974.394,78486.004 457973.884,78486.206 457973.736,78486.179 457973.488,78485.951 457973.386,78481.149 457973.897,78475.512 457974.496,78474.462 457966.821,78477.122 457966.454,78477.831 457966.356,78481.908 457965.794,78482.772 457965.675,78482.937 457965.578,78482.986 457965.394,78482.98 457965.348,78482.068 457958.858,78482.034 457958.616,78481.739 457956.513,78480.822 457949.983,78480.752 457949.842,78478.325 457947.385,78478.041 457947.097,78476.158 457945.19,78476.142 457945.175,78476.128 457945.158,78476.114 457945.143,78476.103 457945.128,78476.093 457945.115,78476.084 457945.101,78476.075 457945.089,78476.068 457945.077,78476.063 457945.067,78476.058 457945.056,78476.054 457945.047,78476.051 457945.038,78476.048 457945.03,78476.047 457945.022,78476.045 457945.016,78476.045 457945.011,78476.044 457945.005,78476.044 457944.999,78476.045 457944.994,78476.046 457944.989,78476.046 457944.983,78476.048 457944.976,78476.05 457944.97,78476.054 457944.962,78476.058 457944.953,78476.063 457944.944,78476.069 457944.934,78476.077 457944.923,78476.085 457944.911,78476.096 457944.898,78476.108 457944.884,78476.122 457944.871,78476.191 457944.801,78476.212 457944.781,78476.232 457944.76,78476.253 457944.74,78476.273 457944.72,78476.294 457944.699,78476.315 457944.678,78476.336 457944.657,78476.357 457944.636,78476.378 457944.616,78476.399 457944.594,78476.421 457944.573,78476.442 457944.552,78476.463 457944.531,78476.484 457944.509,78476.506 457944.487,78476.526 457944.467,78476.547 457944.446,78476.568 457944.426,78476.588 457944.406,78476.609 457944.385,78476.63 457944.364,78476.651 457944.344,78476.672 457944.323,78476.693 457944.302,78476.714 457944.281,78476.735 457944.26,78476.757 457944.239,78476.778 457944.218,78476.8 457944.196,78476.821 457944.175,78476.842 457944.154,78476.863 457944.132,78477.208 457943.789,78485.007 457936.031,78487.112 457933.938,78488.827 457932.232,78491.174 457929.898,78495.661 457928.501,78499.127 457927.421,78501.781 457926.595,78503.322 457926.9,78507.736 457927.774,78508.775 457927.98,78508.962 457927.94,78509.067 457927.78,78509.177 457927.193,78509.182 457927.163,78509.188 457927.134,78509.193 457927.104,78509.199 457927.074,78509.205 457927.045,78509.21 457927.016,78509.216 457926.986,78509.221 457926.957,78509.227 457926.928,78509.232 457926.899,78509.238 457926.87,78509.243 457926.842,78509.248 457926.813,78509.254 457926.784,78509.259 457926.756,78509.265 457926.728,78509.27 457926.698,78509.276 457926.668,78509.282 457926.638,78509.287 457926.609,78509.293 457926.579,78509.299 457926.55,78509.304 457926.52,78509.31 457926.491,78509.316 457926.462,78509.321 457926.433,78509.326 457926.404,78509.332 457926.375,78509.337 457926.346,78509.343 457926.318,78509.348 457926.289,78509.354 457926.26,78509.372 457926.162,78509.379 457926.124,78509.38 457926.115,78509.386 457926.081,78509.391 457926.046,78509.392 457926.034,78509.395 457926.002,78509.398 457925.97,78509.399 457925.956,78509.4 457925.927,78509.401 457925.898,78509.402 457925.889,78509.401 457925.879,78509.4 457925.853,78509.399 457925.828,78509.397 457925.805,78509.394 457925.781,78509.391 457925.758,78509.39 457925.748,78509.386 457925.731,78509.381 457925.71,78509.376 457925.689,78509.368 457925.665,78509.365 457925.656,78509.357 457925.638,78509.35 457925.621,78509.334 457925.591,78509.329 457925.584,78509.323 457925.572,78509.32 457925.567,78509.32 457925.556,78509.319 457925.544,78509.318 457925.53,78509.318 457925.513,78509.318 457925.493,78509.319 457925.472,78509.321 457925.448,78509.324 457925.422,78509.327 457925.395,78509.332 457925.365,78509.338 457925.333,78509.356 457925.235,78509.36 457925.212,78509.363 457925.195,78509.365 457925.174,78509.368 457925.154,78509.369 457925.133,78509.37 457925.113,78509.37 457925.094,78509.371 457925.084,78509.37 457925.07,78509.369 457925.051,78509.368 457925.033,78509.366 457925.007,78509.363 457924.989,78509.359 457924.969,78509.354 457924.945,78509.35 457924.928,78509.345 457924.911,78509.339 457924.892,78509.335 457924.882,78509.329 457924.867,78509.323 457924.852,78509.309 457924.823,78509.301 457924.809,78509.292 457924.793,78509.275 457924.768,78509.266 457924.755,78509.257 457924.743,78509.247 457924.73,78509.238 457924.72,78509.226 457924.708,78509.215 457924.696,78509.194 457924.676,78509.182 457924.666,78509.169 457924.655,78509.148 457924.639,78509.134 457924.629,78509.12 457924.62,78509.104 457924.61,78509.097 457924.606,78509.082 457924.598,78509.066 457924.59,78509.047 457924.58,78509.029 457924.572,78509.011 457924.564,78508.995 457924.558,78508.974 457924.551,78508.955 457924.544,78508.938 457924.539,78508.917 457924.533,78508.895 457924.528,78508.88 457924.524,78508.857 457924.52,78508.592 457924.468,78508.366 457924.541,78508.109 457924.809,78508.049 457925.052,78508.229 457925.225,78508.469 457925.155,78508.632 457924.985,78508.761 457925.01,78508.774 457925.013,78508.788 457925.017,78508.801 457925.02,78508.811 457925.024,78508.822 457925.028,78508.83 457925.031,78508.837 457925.034,78508.844 457925.038,78508.849 457925.04,78508.853 457925.043,78508.858 457925.047,78508.864 457925.053,78508.867 457925.059,78508.868 457925.063,78508.869 457925.068,78508.87 457925.072,78508.87 457925.079,78508.87 457925.086,78508.87 457925.095,78508.87 457925.104,78508.868 457925.117,78508.867 457925.129,78508.864 457925.143,78508.846 457925.241,78508.839 457925.28,78508.838 457925.288,78508.833 457925.323,78508.828 457925.358,78508.826 457925.37,78508.823 457925.402,78508.82 457925.434,78508.819 457925.449,78508.818 457925.478,78508.818 457925.506,78508.817 457925.514,78508.818 457925.525,78508.819 457925.551,78508.82 457925.577,78508.822 457925.6,78508.825 457925.623,78508.828 457925.646,78508.83 457925.656,78508.834 457925.674,78508.839 457925.695,78508.844 457925.715,78508.851 457925.738,78508.856 457925.749,78508.863 457925.766,78508.87 457925.784,78508.886 457925.812,78508.891 457925.821,78508.896 457925.83,78508.899 457925.836,78508.899 457925.847,78508.9 457925.858,78508.901 457925.873,78508.901 457925.89,78508.901 457925.908,78508.9 457925.929,78508.898 457925.954,78508.895 457925.979,78508.891 457926.008,78508.886 457926.037,78508.88 457926.07,78508.862 457926.168,78508.857 457926.196,78508.852 457926.225,78508.846 457926.253,78508.841 457926.281,78508.835 457926.31,78508.83 457926.34,78508.824 457926.369,78508.819 457926.398,78508.813 457926.426,78508.808 457926.456,78508.802 457926.485,78508.796 457926.515,78508.791 457926.545,78508.785 457926.574,78508.779 457926.604,78508.774 457926.634,78508.768 457926.663,78508.763 457926.692,78508.757 457926.72,78508.752 457926.749,78508.746 457926.778,78508.741 457926.807,78508.735 457926.835,78508.73 457926.865,78508.724 457926.894,78508.719 457926.923,78508.713 457926.952,78508.708 457926.982,78508.702 457927.011,78508.697 457927.041,78508.691 457927.071,78508.685 457927.101,78508.622 457927.44,78507.834 457927.284,78503.42 457926.41,78501.813 457926.091,78501.693 457926.098,78498.979 457926.943,78495.513 457928.023,78490.967 457929.439,78490.865 457929.501,78488.475 457931.878,78486.76 457933.584,78484.655 457935.677,78476.856 457943.435,78476.51 457943.778,78476.489 457943.8,78476.467 457943.821,78476.446 457943.842,78476.425 457943.863,78476.404 457943.884,78476.383 457943.905,78476.362 457943.926,78476.341 457943.947,78476.32 457943.968,78476.299 457943.989,78476.278 457944.009,78476.258 457944.03,78476.237 457944.05,78476.216 457944.071,78476.196 457944.091,78476.175 457944.112,78476.153 457944.134,78476.131 457944.155,78476.11 457944.176,78476.088 457944.198,78476.067 457944.219,78476.046 457944.24,78476.025 457944.261,78476.004 457944.282,78475.983 457944.303,78475.962 457944.324,78475.942 457944.344,78475.921 457944.365,78475.9 457944.386,78475.879 457944.406,78475.859 457944.427,78475.839 457944.447,78475.768 457944.517,78475.748 457944.537,78475.735 457944.552,78475.717 457944.572,78475.698 457944.594,78475.686 457944.61,78475.67 457944.632,78475.655 457944.653,78475.642 457944.673,78475.63 457944.694,78475.617 457944.716,78475.605 457944.741,78475.596 457944.762,78475.587 457944.782,78475.58 457944.798,78475.576 457944.812,78475.57 457944.833,78475.563 457944.854,78475.556 457944.884,78475.552 457944.907,78475.549 457944.928,78475.545 457944.961,78475.545 457944.983,78475.544 457945.005,78475.544 457945.013,78475.545 457945.037,78475.547 457945.059,78475.549 457945.08,78475.552 457945.098,78475.554 457945.108,78475.558 457945.128,78475.562 457945.149,78475.569 457945.174,78475.576 457945.195,78475.583 457945.216,78475.585 457945.222,78475.592 457945.238,78475.601 457945.258,78475.61 457945.279,78475.62 457945.299,78475.632 457945.32,78475.644 457945.342,78475.653 457945.357,78475.667 457945.378,78475.681 457945.4,78475.691 457945.413,78475.708 457945.435,78475.725 457945.456,78475.73 457945.463,78475.734 457945.468,78475.753 457945.489,78475.771 457945.51,78475.781 457945.521,78475.802 457945.542,78477.685 457947.449,78477.969 457947.737,78480.338 457950.135,78481.243 457956.583,78481.538 457958.686,78481.572 457958.928,78482.456 457965.214,78481.84 457965.298,78477.763 457965.86,78477.054 457965.958,78474.147 457966.359,78473.982 457966.456,78473.933 457966.641,78475.049 457974.804,78475.143 457974.967,78475.323 457975.019)))');
SELECT ST_IsValid('SRID=28992;POLYGON((78499.527 457927.715,78501.803 457927.007,78503.244 457927.292,78499.527 457927.715))');

SELECT ST_Intersects('SRID=28992;GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POLYGON((78499.527 457927.715,78501.803 457927.007,78503.244 457927.292,78503.25 457927.293,78507.658 457928.166,78508.442 457928.322,78508.52 457928.325,78508.596 457928.304,78508.661 457928.261,78508.709 457928.199,78508.736 457928.126,78509.095 457926.316,78509.097 457926.238,78509.075 457926.163,78509.031 457926.099,78508.97 457926.051,78508.896 457926.025,78508.818 457926.022,78508.743 457926.043,78508.679 457926.087,78508.631 457926.148,78508.604 457926.221,78508.294 457927.783,78507.756 457927.676,78503.342 457926.802,78503.336 457926.801,78501.835 457926.503,78501.774 457926.499,78501.715 457926.51,78499.379 457927.237,78499.097 457927.325,78495.631 457928.405,78491.179 457929.791,78491.124 457929.816,78491.077 457929.853,78488.757 457932.162,78487.042 457933.868,78484.937 457935.961,78477.138 457943.719,78476.817 457944.038,78476.768 457944.106,78476.556 457944.545,78476.516 457944.613,78476.513 457944.619,78476.476 457944.689,78476.438 457944.758,78476.434 457944.766,78476.403 457944.83,78476.373 457944.892,78476.368 457944.903,78476.344 457944.959,78476.319 457945.015,78476.314 457945.029,78476.296 457945.078,78476.278 457945.128,78476.271 457945.148,78476.26 457945.191,78476.249 457945.234,78476.244 457945.254,78476.243 457945.264,78476.238 457945.3,78476.233 457945.336,78476.231 457945.369,78476.231 457945.383,78476.233 457945.412,78476.234 457945.442,78476.238 457945.47,78476.249 457945.513,78476.257 457945.535,78476.263 457945.551,78476.27 457945.569,78476.278 457945.584,78476.285 457945.6,78476.292 457945.616,78476.301 457945.632,78476.31 457945.648,78476.314 457945.655,78476.318 457945.662,78476.328 457945.679,78476.338 457945.695,78476.346 457945.707,78476.358 457945.724,78476.37 457945.741,78476.378 457945.751,78476.391 457945.768,78476.404 457945.785,78476.411 457945.794,78476.427 457945.812,78476.442 457945.83,78476.449 457945.838,78476.465 457945.856,78476.482 457945.874,78476.488 457945.88,78476.506 457945.898,78477.863 457947.273,78478.147 457947.561,78480.574 457950.018,78481.491 457956.548,78481.786 457958.651,78481.82 457958.893,78482.33 457962.522,78482.662 457964.882,78482.666 457964.913,78482.67 457964.944,78482.675 457964.975,78482.679 457965.006,78482.683 457965.037,78482.688 457965.068,78482.692 457965.099,78482.696 457965.13,78482.701 457965.161,78482.705 457965.192,78482.71 457965.222,78482.714 457965.254,78482.718 457965.284,78482.723 457965.315,78482.727 457965.346,78482.732 457965.377,78482.736 457965.407,78482.74 457965.438,78482.744 457965.469,78482.748 457965.5,78482.753 457965.531,78482.757 457965.562,78482.761 457965.594,78482.764 457965.609,78482.787 457965.684,78482.831 457965.748,78482.894 457965.795,78482.968 457965.821,78483.046 457965.822,78483.121 457965.799,78483.185 457965.754,78483.232 457965.691,78483.257 457965.617,78483.259 457965.539,78483.256 457965.524,78483.252 457965.494,78483.248 457965.463,78483.244 457965.432,78483.239 457965.401,78483.235 457965.37,78483.231 457965.339,78483.227 457965.307,78483.222 457965.276,78483.218 457965.245,78483.213 457965.214,78483.209 457965.183,78483.205 457965.153,78483.2 457965.122,78483.196 457965.09,78483.192 457965.06,78483.187 457965.029,78483.183 457964.998,78483.178 457964.967,78483.174 457964.936,78483.17 457964.905,78483.165 457964.874,78483.161 457964.843,78483.157 457964.812,78482.826 457962.452,78482.316 457958.823,78482.282 457958.581,78481.987 457956.478,78481.058 457949.866,78481.034 457949.79,78480.988 457949.725,78478.503 457947.209,78478.219 457946.921,78476.862 457945.548,78476.847 457945.532,78476.833 457945.517,78476.82 457945.502,78476.808 457945.488,78476.796 457945.475,78476.786 457945.462,78476.776 457945.448,78476.768 457945.437,78476.76 457945.427,78476.753 457945.415,78476.746 457945.404,78476.742 457945.395,78476.737 457945.386,78476.732 457945.377,78476.733 457945.367,78476.736 457945.347,78476.743 457945.32,78476.752 457945.287,78476.766 457945.249,78476.781 457945.206,78476.802 457945.158,78476.824 457945.108,78476.852 457945.049,78476.881 457944.991,78476.916 457944.925,78476.953 457944.856,78476.994 457944.785,78477.002 457944.77,78477.2 457944.362,78477.49 457944.073,78485.289 457936.315,78487.394 457934.222,78489.109 457932.516,78491.386 457930.25,78495.779 457928.883,78499.246 457927.803,78499.527 457927.715)),POLYGON((78462.657 457906.654,78462.579 457906.653,78462.505 457906.675,78462.441 457906.72,78462.394 457906.782,78462.368 457906.856,78462.366 457906.934,78462.412 457907.271,78461.151 457908.462,78461.103 457908.524,78461.077 457908.598,78461.074 457908.676,78461.096 457908.751,78461.141 457908.816,78461.203 457908.864,78461.276 457908.89,78461.354 457908.892,78461.429 457908.87,78461.494 457908.826,78462.848 457907.546,78462.896 457907.484,78462.922 457907.41,78462.924 457907.331,78462.862 457906.867,78462.839 457906.791,78462.794 457906.727,78462.732 457906.68,78462.657 457906.654)),POLYGON((79373.448 458075.366,79373.244 458075.421,79373.155 458075.612,79373.155 458079.509,79373.28 458079.726,79373.53 458079.726,79373.655 458079.509,79373.655 458075.612,79373.597 458075.452,79373.448 458075.366)),POLYGON((78475.323 457975.019,78481.202 457974.394,78486.004 457973.884,78486.206 457973.736,78486.179 457973.488,78485.951 457973.386,78481.149 457973.897,78475.512 457974.496,78474.462 457966.821,78477.122 457966.454,78477.831 457966.356,78481.908 457965.794,78482.772 457965.675,78482.937 457965.578,78482.986 457965.394,78482.98 457965.348,78482.068 457958.858,78482.034 457958.616,78481.739 457956.513,78480.822 457949.983,78480.752 457949.842,78478.325 457947.385,78478.041 457947.097,78476.158 457945.19,78476.142 457945.175,78476.128 457945.158,78476.114 457945.143,78476.103 457945.128,78476.093 457945.115,78476.084 457945.101,78476.075 457945.089,78476.068 457945.077,78476.063 457945.067,78476.058 457945.056,78476.054 457945.047,78476.051 457945.038,78476.048 457945.03,78476.047 457945.022,78476.045 457945.016,78476.045 457945.011,78476.044 457945.005,78476.044 457944.999,78476.045 457944.994,78476.046 457944.989,78476.046 457944.983,78476.048 457944.976,78476.05 457944.97,78476.054 457944.962,78476.058 457944.953,78476.063 457944.944,78476.069 457944.934,78476.077 457944.923,78476.085 457944.911,78476.096 457944.898,78476.108 457944.884,78476.122 457944.871,78476.191 457944.801,78476.212 457944.781,78476.232 457944.76,78476.253 457944.74,78476.273 457944.72,78476.294 457944.699,78476.315 457944.678,78476.336 457944.657,78476.357 457944.636,78476.378 457944.616,78476.399 457944.594,78476.421 457944.573,78476.442 457944.552,78476.463 457944.531,78476.484 457944.509,78476.506 457944.487,78476.526 457944.467,78476.547 457944.446,78476.568 457944.426,78476.588 457944.406,78476.609 457944.385,78476.63 457944.364,78476.651 457944.344,78476.672 457944.323,78476.693 457944.302,78476.714 457944.281,78476.735 457944.26,78476.757 457944.239,78476.778 457944.218,78476.8 457944.196,78476.821 457944.175,78476.842 457944.154,78476.863 457944.132,78477.208 457943.789,78485.007 457936.031,78487.112 457933.938,78488.827 457932.232,78491.174 457929.898,78495.661 457928.501,78499.127 457927.421,78501.781 457926.595,78503.322 457926.9,78507.736 457927.774,78508.775 457927.98,78508.962 457927.94,78509.067 457927.78,78509.177 457927.193,78509.182 457927.163,78509.188 457927.134,78509.193 457927.104,78509.199 457927.074,78509.205 457927.045,78509.21 457927.016,78509.216 457926.986,78509.221 457926.957,78509.227 457926.928,78509.232 457926.899,78509.238 457926.87,78509.243 457926.842,78509.248 457926.813,78509.254 457926.784,78509.259 457926.756,78509.265 457926.728,78509.27 457926.698,78509.276 457926.668,78509.282 457926.638,78509.287 457926.609,78509.293 457926.579,78509.299 457926.55,78509.304 457926.52,78509.31 457926.491,78509.316 457926.462,78509.321 457926.433,78509.326 457926.404,78509.332 457926.375,78509.337 457926.346,78509.343 457926.318,78509.348 457926.289,78509.354 457926.26,78509.372 457926.162,78509.379 457926.124,78509.38 457926.115,78509.386 457926.081,78509.391 457926.046,78509.392 457926.034,78509.395 457926.002,78509.398 457925.97,78509.399 457925.956,78509.4 457925.927,78509.401 457925.898,78509.402 457925.889,78509.401 457925.879,78509.4 457925.853,78509.399 457925.828,78509.397 457925.805,78509.394 457925.781,78509.391 457925.758,78509.39 457925.748,78509.386 457925.731,78509.381 457925.71,78509.376 457925.689,78509.368 457925.665,78509.365 457925.656,78509.357 457925.638,78509.35 457925.621,78509.334 457925.591,78509.329 457925.584,78509.323 457925.572,78509.32 457925.567,78509.32 457925.556,78509.319 457925.544,78509.318 457925.53,78509.318 457925.513,78509.318 457925.493,78509.319 457925.472,78509.321 457925.448,78509.324 457925.422,78509.327 457925.395,78509.332 457925.365,78509.338 457925.333,78509.356 457925.235,78509.36 457925.212,78509.363 457925.195,78509.365 457925.174,78509.368 457925.154,78509.369 457925.133,78509.37 457925.113,78509.37 457925.094,78509.371 457925.084,78509.37 457925.07,78509.369 457925.051,78509.368 457925.033,78509.366 457925.007,78509.363 457924.989,78509.359 457924.969,78509.354 457924.945,78509.35 457924.928,78509.345 457924.911,78509.339 457924.892,78509.335 457924.882,78509.329 457924.867,78509.323 457924.852,78509.309 457924.823,78509.301 457924.809,78509.292 457924.793,78509.275 457924.768,78509.266 457924.755,78509.257 457924.743,78509.247 457924.73,78509.238 457924.72,78509.226 457924.708,78509.215 457924.696,78509.194 457924.676,78509.182 457924.666,78509.169 457924.655,78509.148 457924.639,78509.134 457924.629,78509.12 457924.62,78509.104 457924.61,78509.097 457924.606,78509.082 457924.598,78509.066 457924.59,78509.047 457924.58,78509.029 457924.572,78509.011 457924.564,78508.995 457924.558,78508.974 457924.551,78508.955 457924.544,78508.938 457924.539,78508.917 457924.533,78508.895 457924.528,78508.88 457924.524,78508.857 457924.52,78508.592 457924.468,78508.366 457924.541,78508.109 457924.809,78508.049 457925.052,78508.229 457925.225,78508.469 457925.155,78508.632 457924.985,78508.761 457925.01,78508.774 457925.013,78508.788 457925.017,78508.801 457925.02,78508.811 457925.024,78508.822 457925.028,78508.83 457925.031,78508.837 457925.034,78508.844 457925.038,78508.849 457925.04,78508.853 457925.043,78508.858 457925.047,78508.864 457925.053,78508.867 457925.059,78508.868 457925.063,78508.869 457925.068,78508.87 457925.072,78508.87 457925.079,78508.87 457925.086,78508.87 457925.095,78508.87 457925.104,78508.868 457925.117,78508.867 457925.129,78508.864 457925.143,78508.846 457925.241,78508.839 457925.28,78508.838 457925.288,78508.833 457925.323,78508.828 457925.358,78508.826 457925.37,78508.823 457925.402,78508.82 457925.434,78508.819 457925.449,78508.818 457925.478,78508.818 457925.506,78508.817 457925.514,78508.818 457925.525,78508.819 457925.551,78508.82 457925.577,78508.822 457925.6,78508.825 457925.623,78508.828 457925.646,78508.83 457925.656,78508.834 457925.674,78508.839 457925.695,78508.844 457925.715,78508.851 457925.738,78508.856 457925.749,78508.863 457925.766,78508.87 457925.784,78508.886 457925.812,78508.891 457925.821,78508.896 457925.83,78508.899 457925.836,78508.899 457925.847,78508.9 457925.858,78508.901 457925.873,78508.901 457925.89,78508.901 457925.908,78508.9 457925.929,78508.898 457925.954,78508.895 457925.979,78508.891 457926.008,78508.886 457926.037,78508.88 457926.07,78508.862 457926.168,78508.857 457926.196,78508.852 457926.225,78508.846 457926.253,78508.841 457926.281,78508.835 457926.31,78508.83 457926.34,78508.824 457926.369,78508.819 457926.398,78508.813 457926.426,78508.808 457926.456,78508.802 457926.485,78508.796 457926.515,78508.791 457926.545,78508.785 457926.574,78508.779 457926.604,78508.774 457926.634,78508.768 457926.663,78508.763 457926.692,78508.757 457926.72,78508.752 457926.749,78508.746 457926.778,78508.741 457926.807,78508.735 457926.835,78508.73 457926.865,78508.724 457926.894,78508.719 457926.923,78508.713 457926.952,78508.708 457926.982,78508.702 457927.011,78508.697 457927.041,78508.691 457927.071,78508.685 457927.101,78508.622 457927.44,78507.834 457927.284,78503.42 457926.41,78501.813 457926.091,78501.693 457926.098,78498.979 457926.943,78495.513 457928.023,78490.967 457929.439,78490.865 457929.501,78488.475 457931.878,78486.76 457933.584,78484.655 457935.677,78476.856 457943.435,78476.51 457943.778,78476.489 457943.8,78476.467 457943.821,78476.446 457943.842,78476.425 457943.863,78476.404 457943.884,78476.383 457943.905,78476.362 457943.926,78476.341 457943.947,78476.32 457943.968,78476.299 457943.989,78476.278 457944.009,78476.258 457944.03,78476.237 457944.05,78476.216 457944.071,78476.196 457944.091,78476.175 457944.112,78476.153 457944.134,78476.131 457944.155,78476.11 457944.176,78476.088 457944.198,78476.067 457944.219,78476.046 457944.24,78476.025 457944.261,78476.004 457944.282,78475.983 457944.303,78475.962 457944.324,78475.942 457944.344,78475.921 457944.365,78475.9 457944.386,78475.879 457944.406,78475.859 457944.427,78475.839 457944.447,78475.768 457944.517,78475.748 457944.537,78475.735 457944.552,78475.717 457944.572,78475.698 457944.594,78475.686 457944.61,78475.67 457944.632,78475.655 457944.653,78475.642 457944.673,78475.63 457944.694,78475.617 457944.716,78475.605 457944.741,78475.596 457944.762,78475.587 457944.782,78475.58 457944.798,78475.576 457944.812,78475.57 457944.833,78475.563 457944.854,78475.556 457944.884,78475.552 457944.907,78475.549 457944.928,78475.545 457944.961,78475.545 457944.983,78475.544 457945.005,78475.544 457945.013,78475.545 457945.037,78475.547 457945.059,78475.549 457945.08,78475.552 457945.098,78475.554 457945.108,78475.558 457945.128,78475.562 457945.149,78475.569 457945.174,78475.576 457945.195,78475.583 457945.216,78475.585 457945.222,78475.592 457945.238,78475.601 457945.258,78475.61 457945.279,78475.62 457945.299,78475.632 457945.32,78475.644 457945.342,78475.653 457945.357,78475.667 457945.378,78475.681 457945.4,78475.691 457945.413,78475.708 457945.435,78475.725 457945.456,78475.73 457945.463,78475.734 457945.468,78475.753 457945.489,78475.771 457945.51,78475.781 457945.521,78475.802 457945.542,78477.685 457947.449,78477.969 457947.737,78480.338 457950.135,78481.243 457956.583,78481.538 457958.686,78481.572 457958.928,78482.456 457965.214,78481.84 457965.298,78477.763 457965.86,78477.054 457965.958,78474.147 457966.359,78473.982 457966.456,78473.933 457966.641,78475.049 457974.804,78475.143 457974.967,78475.323 457975.019)))', 'SRID=28992;POLYGON((78499.527 457927.715,78501.803 457927.007,78503.244 457927.292,78499.527 457927.715))');
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Topology operations are probably not honored on collections, just simple features.

Comment: The result is invalid so you get an error, try snapping to a grid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*GeometryCollections* are tedious to work with, both on a low-level algorithmic way as well as in and beyond SQL. You may want to bring this up to the JTS/GEOS/PostGIS teams as a bug report, especially since this is a homogeneous collection and should be comparably simple to handle.

However, you really want to avoid having/generating ***homogeneous*** *GeometryCollections* in the first place - there is no point in them, and their respective *Multi* geometries are much better supported!

If you are stuck with them you can workaround your issue by either

- unifying a ***homogeneous*** *GeometryCollection*:

  ```
  SELECT
    ST_Intersects(
      -- this is here to demonstrate that you can safely call ST_UnaryUnion with all types; it adds overhead, though, so you want to avoid if possible...
      ST_UnaryUnion('SRID=28992;POLYGON((78499.527 457927.715,78501.803 457927.007,78503.244 457927.292,78499.527 457927.715))'),
      -- ...but it does the trick for the collection
      ST_UnaryUnion('<GEOMETRYCOLLECTION>')
    )
  ;
  ```
- explode and iteratively check for intersection on ***heterogeneous*** *GeometryCollections*; there are two options here:

  - check and return all intersecting parts individually:

    ```
    SELECT
      dmp.path[1] AS part_id,
      dmp.geom
    FROM
      ST_Dump('<GEOMETRYCOLLECTION>') AS dmp
    WHERE
      ST_Intersects(dmp.geom, 'SRID=28992;POLYGON((78499.527 457927.715,78501.803 457927.007,78503.244 457927.292,78499.527 457927.715))')
    ;
    ```
  - collectively check if one of the parts intersects:

    ```
    SELECT
      EXISTS (
        SELECT
          1
        FROM
          ST_Dump('<GEOMETRYCOLLECTION>') AS dmp
        WHERE
          ST_Intersects(dmp.geom, 'SRID=28992;POLYGON((78499.527 457927.715,78501.803 457927.007,78503.244 457927.292,78499.527 457927.715))')
      )
    ;
    ```

You can extend this easily to be applicable on one or more tables instead, if your constant values are just an example.

Comment: Correct.  PostGIS (and GEOS) only partially support topological predicates on GeometryCollections.  A new algorithm is in the works to support this, so stay tuned.

Comment: this is a homogeneous collection, but it contains overlapping polygons, and so in fact is not easy to handle!  Your approaches are the best available right now.

Comment: @dr_jts well, the part-overlap sure rules out transformation into a *MultiPolygon* without dissolving first. But as all point-set operations need a full disassembly and iteration of and over the input object primitives anyways I don't see the complication, really - after all, all my latter approach is doing is a sequential pass-by of collection parts to the predicate checkup, which also elegantly handles multi-part geometries downstream in a similarly procedural way. Point-set *manipulations* are cumbersome to handle, I am sure, but likely easier on homogeneous collections.

Comment: yes, it's relatively easy to evaluate `intersects` in a piecewise fashion (as you have done).  Other predicates (like `contains`) can't be computed that way, and that's what I was thinking of, since I'm currently deep into building new logic to handle them!

Comment: In fact GEOS 3.12 changed the way it evaluates `intersects`, so this query *should* work in that version. But it's not for me - so some debugging required.